# Powerline is not displaying special symbols

Tags: linux, bash, powerline

can you help me to know why PowerLine Status is not showing special symbols in shell?

I'm working on Debian 8.3 and Powerline installed in this way: https://www.tecmint.com/powerline-adds-powerful-statuslines-and-prompts-to-vim-and-bash/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly a limitation of the bitmap font used by the terminal emulator. If you have any option to switch to a TrueType font, try one that looks nice (though there might be none that looks exactly the same as what you're used to). Lucida Console or Consolas seem to be popular choices, or you can get some more suggestions [here](http://wesbos.com/programming-fonts/).

Comment: I'm trying to work and user Powerline status over ssh in MobaXTerm. Should I install powerline patched fonts on my windows end?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of these programs so I can't tell for sure. If there is an actual set of Powerline-patched fonts, sure, that would be the first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing powerline fonts. It should work

[powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)

Also powerline-shell config changes from shell to shell

Follow the steps given in

[powerline-shell-github-page](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell)